# CMPedometer StepCounting not Available

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-motion

My code is:

```
if ([CMPedometer isStepCountingAvailable]) {

        self.pedometer = [[CMPedometer alloc] init];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Step counting is not available on this device!");
        [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"Step counting is not available on this device!"];
    }
```

When i run it on iOS8 and later devices, it says:

> Step counting is not available on this device!

How can i make it available for step counting ?

Comment: What is the device that you are testing on?

Comment: Is it accepted to show a message to the user like this? I am also planning to implement the same in my app just curious to know

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is correct and it yields the expected result. The iPhone 5 does not have the hardware (the Apple M7 chip) to track steps, so step counting is not available.

You need at least an iPhone 5s

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Can i calculate Elevation using pedometer ?

Comment: @Matthias I am trying the same code in my iPhone 5S (also in iPhone 5C) but its not working for me......is it because of the fact that Apple M7 chip not available in these devices also??

Comment: @Matthias how can Apple make such an API which is not being supported by many of the devices...because of hardware? Please tell how I can implement the foot step counting using CMPedometer or is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone 4s, 5 and 5c do not have the M7 Motion Sensor co-processor so they will not record steps. The iPhone 5s, 6 and 6 Plus all have a motion co-processor.