# Alternative to CMPedometer to calculate number of steps with accelerometer on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, accelerometer, gyroscope

Since CMPedometer is not available for below iPhone5S.

[CMPedometer StepCounting not Available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27479118/cmpedometer-stepcounting-not-available)

Is there an algorithm code that we can use to program number of steps with the accelerometer on ios ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can detect step Event using accelerometer data from `CMMotionManager`

```
protected CMMotionManager _motionManager;
public event EventHandler<bool> OnMotion;

public double ACCEL_DETECTION_LIMIT = 0.31;
private const double ACCEL_REDUCE_SPEED = 0.9;

private double accel = -1;
private double accelCurrent = 0;

private void StartAccelerometerUpdates()
    {
        if (_motionManager.AccelerometerAvailable)
            _motionManager.AccelerometerUpdateInterval = ACCEL_UPDATE_INTERVAL;
        _motionManager.StartAccelerometerUpdates (NSOperationQueue.MainQueue, AccelerometerDataUpdatedHandler);
    }   

public void AccelerometerDataUpdatedHandler(CMAccelerometerData data, NSError error)
        {           
        double x = data.Acceleration.X;
        double y = data.Acceleration.Y;
        double z = data.Acceleration.Z;

        double accelLast = accelCurrent;
        accelCurrent = Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);
        double delta = accelCurrent - accelLast;
        accel = accel * ACCEL_REDUCE_SPEED + delta;

        var didStep = OnMotion;

        if (accel > ACCEL_DETECTION_LIMIT) 
        {                                           
            didStep (this, true);//maked a step
        } else {
            didStep (this, false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your solution. it somehow worked with some flaws in it. Your code for some reason on initial load it comes to 11 steps then only i starts to detect the steps correctly. I played around ACCEL_DETECTION_LIMIT  it had some better initial load but accuracy is off. Here is more explanation. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d8563c4c8fc8ba874ba6. Any idea whats the problem ?

Comment: @Axil fixed a bug, just set  `private double accel` to  -1

Answer (score 1):

IOS aside, there is no simple solution to create an accurate pedometer using just the accelerometer output; it's just to noisy. Using the output from a gyroscope(where available) to filter the output would increase the accuracy.

But a crude here's a crude approach to wiring code for a pedometer:
- steps are detected as a variation in the acceleration detected on the Z axis. Assuming you know the default acceleration(the impact of gravity) here's how you do it:

```
float g = (x * x + y * y + z * z) / (GRAVITY_VALUE * GRAVITY_VALUE)
```

Your threshold is `g=1` (this is what you would see when standing still). Spikes in this value represent steps. So all you have to do is count the spikes. Please mind here that a simple g>1 will not do, as for one step, the g value will increase for a certain amount of time and then go back (if you plot the value over time, it should look like a sin wave when there is a step - essentially you want to count the sin waves)

Mind you that this is just something to get you started; you will have to add more complexity to it to increase accuracy. 
Things like: 
   - hysteresis to avoid false step detection
   - filtering the accelerometer output 
   - figuring out the step intervals 
Are not included here and should be experimented with.

Comment: ok guess its more of research we have to work out for this. have you tried the first ? that works but just weird behaviour at the beginning of the load. If we can fine tune that, it will just work fine. thanks

Comment: I used this formula plus a lot more when building an ecompass. The calibration part can be a bit of hit and miss, especially when working with accelerometers only. But one done correctly it should be simple enough.